# Access input and middle layers output in in loss function for GAN like model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement a GAN like model which requires access to input and generator output for the combined model loss function but every attempt I made has lead to failure.

this is what I have done so far

```
class GAN_MNIST:
def __init__(self, sampling_matrix, n_critic=5, clip_value=0.01, lr=5e-5):

    img_shape = [28, 28, 1]
    latent_dim = np.sum(sampling_matrix != 0)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr)

    self.img_shape = img_shape
    self.img_rows = img_shape[0]
    self.img_cols = img_shape[1]
    self.img_channels = img_shape[2]
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.n_critic = n_critic
    self.clip_value = clip_value
    self.optimizer = optimizer
    self.sampling_matrix = sampling_matrix

    #         building critic
    self.critic = self.build_critic()
    self.critic.compile(loss=self.wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    #         building the combined model
    self.generator = self.build_generator()
    measurement_input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,), name='Measurement_layer_input')
    img_input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=self.img_shape, name="imag_Input")
    generated_images_input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=self.img_shape, name="Generated_imgs")
    generated_images = self.generator(measurement_input_layer)
    self.critic.trainable = False
    critic_output = self.critic(generated_images)
    self.combined = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[img_input_layer, measurement_input_layer, generated_images_input_layer],
        outputs=critic_output)

    self.combined.compile(
        loss=self.generator_loss(img_input_layer, measurement_input_layer, generated_images_input_layer),
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=['accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)

def wasserstein_loss(self, y_pred, y_true):

    return K.mean(y_true * y_pred)

def build_generator(self):

    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,)))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=7 * 7 * 256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))

    model.add(SubpixelConv2d(upsampling_factor=2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('selu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('selu'))

    model.add(SubpixelConv2d(upsampling_factor=2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('selu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('selu'))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.4))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation('tanh'))
    return model

def build_critic(self):

    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.img_shape)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.2))

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1024))

    return model

def show_sample_images(self, epoch):
    rows, cols = 5, 5
    noise = np.random.randn(rows * cols, self.latent_dim)
    gen_imgs = self.generator(noise)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(16, 12))
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            ax[i, j].imshow(gen_imgs[i * rows + j, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')

    plt.show()

def sample_imgs(self, imgs):

    ret_val = tf.boolean_mask(imgs, self.sampling_matrix, axis=1)
    return ret_val

def train(self, n_epochs, batch_size=128, sample_interval=50):
    (x_train, _), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = (x_train.astype('float32') - 127.5) / 127.5
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3)

    y_real = -np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    y_fake = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    self.critic.trainable = True
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):

        for _ in range(self.n_critic):

            #               Training the Critic

            idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], batch_size)
            imgs = x_train[idx]
            sampled_imgs = self.sample_imgs(imgs)
            generated_imgs = self.generator(sampled_imgs)

            c_loss_real = self.critic.train_on_batch(imgs, y_real)
            c_loss_fake = self.critic.train_on_batch(generated_imgs, y_fake)

            critic_total_loss = np.add(c_loss_fake, c_loss_real) / 2

            #                 clipping_critic_wieghts
            for l in self.critic.layers:
                weights = l.get_weights()
                weights = [np.clip(w, -self.clip_value, self.clip_value) for w in weights]
                l.set_weights(weights)

        #             train Generator
        self.critic.trainable = False
        #             print(sampled_imgs)
        g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch((imgs, sampled_imgs.numpy(), generated_imgs.numpy()), y_real)

        print('%d [C_loss : %f] [G_loss: %f]' % (epoch, 1 - critic_total_loss[0], 1 - g_loss[0]))

        if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
            self.show_sample_images(epoch)

def generator_loss(self, input_imgs, measurement_vectors, generated_img):

    def loss(y_pred, y_true):

        wasserstein_loss = self.wasserstein_loss(y_pred, y_true)

        measure_of_generated = self.sample_imgs(input_imgs)
        measure_of_input = self.sample_imgs(generated_img)


        measure_ment_loss = K.mean(K.square(measure_of_input - measure_of_generated))
        generation_loss = K.mean(K.square(input_imgs - generated_img))
        return wasserstein_loss + measure_ment_loss + generation_loss

    return loss
```

the whole Idea is to use random samples of an image to reconstruct the original one.to do this three different losses are needed in the combined model(generator +discriminator). a regeneration loss which is mean squared error of the input image and the generated one and measurement loss which is the MSE of the input image sample vector and generated sample vector and a wasserstein loss which uses the discriminator outputs. I have made the combined model with three different input layer and have passed them to the loss function. In the training function after training the discriminator I pass the the input image ,measurement vectors and generated images as inputs to the combined model but I am receiving the following error

TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.

I don't know what I am doing wrong
thank you  in Advance

Comment: It's likely related to the generator_loss function.  Recent versions of TF have trouble with passing keras input tensors to custom loss functions.  See e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47311.  Disabling eager execution helps some people but may break other things.